# Minifying dynamically loaded javascript whilst leaving it editable

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

So, I am using CodeIgniter to develop a website.

I noticed I had about ten javascript files all being loaded in my header even though they were not all being used on a given page.

As such I now pass an array to my header view which contains a list of the javascript files which need to be included. This way only the files I need on a given page are loaded.

I ran my site through a speed test, and although it is pretty fast it flagged up the numerous JS file loads and said to combine them into one file, and minify it.

I have my JS files as seperate files so I can use them as above, and also so if i want to edit my tabs js, I can easily find it in tabs.js

Combining all the javascripts into one file would remove the benefits above. Minifying them would make them a lot of effort to edit..

Is there a way of combining the JS files and minifying them when the server tries to load them, or any way to avoid the problems above?

Thanks

Comment: Usually, I have some sort of build script that I run after editing any js file. This script then combines all needed files in the correct order and runs, e.g., the google closure compiler in order to generate a minified version. You're not supposed to work on a single, minified file - just produce it as described above and upload that file to your server and serve it to the clients.

Comment: Could you clarify a little more? So are you suggesting I keep my files as is - separate for ease of editing but develop a build script which connects to Google closure compiler and minifies them?

Comment: Exactly, multiple files etc. are good for you as a developer but a single, minified file is best for the client (only one HTTP request needed, no unnecessary data transferred) - consider this tiny Python script as an example: https://github.com/buero-fuer-ideen/Simrou/blob/master/make.py (does CoffeeScript to JavaScript compilation instead of appending files, but at least the closure compiler call is in there).

Comment: So.. i've had a read, and it seems very much doable in PHP to generate a single compiled and minified js file. As each page on the site requires different JS combinations on editing a given js file, I would have to rerun my 'compiler' to regenerate all these separate minified javascript files. Each page would have to specify which compiled combo file it needs. Given that before committing and pushing id have to run the compiler, then one would have to check the compiler has successfully worked etc it seems like a lot of effort.. Is it really worth it?

Comment: No, probably not. But most the time, you can simply compile everything into a single file and serve that all the time. This would increase the file size but since the client is usually able to cache js files, the file is actually transferred just once.